# Calculation only if variables are not null

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a long Python program, with many calculations on dataframe columns.

How could I do globally to tell my program to not make calculations if any of the column used in the calculation is nan and display nan in the new column?

Thanks

Comment: have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
cols_to_use = ['col1', 'col2']
if df[cols_to_use].isna().any().any():
    print('skipping computation')
else:
    # perform computation
```

Variant to only handle the computation/no-computation:

```
cols_to_use = ['col1', 'col2']
if df[cols_to_use].notna().all().all():
    # perform computation
```